# HTML YouTube embed does not play as expected

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api

So I've searched around and I still can't find a solution to my issue. I have a YouTube video embedded in my page that was working fine until a couple of days ago. It will play as expected for about for seconds, then stop and return to the thumbnail. Nothing happens when I try to play it again. Here's my iFrame code that I copypasted from YouTube. I also have some JS running in the background that highlights text as the video plays, but I don't think that's affecting it at all.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/03HOhd4GI1w" frameborder="0" 
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz4dh63u/):

```
< iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/03HOhd4GI1w" frameborder="0" 
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe >
```

and it's working fine.

[image]

Maybe try to check other factors.